# Convert E-Mail to Text - reformime

Tags: bash

First, what I want to do:

- I want to send my handwritten notes that I have on my Remarkable (converted) via e-mail to my mailbox.
- I retrieve my mailbox with getmail and save the mails locally.
- I then want to convert the mails (e-mail format) into text.
  Send the text file via webdav to my Nextcloud server so that the note is available in the app.

I find the following command very good:

```
F=/path/to/file  
reformime -e -s $(reformime -i <$F | fgrep 'content-type: text/plain' | head -n1 | cut -c 10- ) <$F > file.txt
```

The above command works for emails sent by a normal mail client.
An e-mail sent by Remarkable gives me the following error when converting: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

**Excerpt e-mail from client:**

```
X-CMAE-Envelope: 
MS4xfA2xbyQ//lzABNRHb8Owbn2q85OGHF5woA2zecQmWfP34ITLP1+7URNVzTP8FH22v0GsDm468r+OHNHUg2mXUPylSWAjPhu7os3WCo8tzghm1RWpN7U0
oz8YZDkiHRSOmCEYq3Vy8sw5QyTnqPEHp5Pi04lCBrhILKiGfkMCW/WeDhgBrlnoscipapZOym4H1IHf616HEG/OySE4QQRaUpg=
X-getmail-retrieved-from-mailbox: INBOX

----_com.samsung.android.email_11924222509547450
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

TGVvbiBXYXJlIHZvbiBNaXI6LSBMb2dpdGVjaCBMZW5rcmFkIHQgSGFuZGVsLSBQUyA0IGlua2wu
IDIgY29udHJvbGxlci0gTGVub3ZvIE1vbml0b3JWb24gbWVpbmVtL21laW5lciBHYWxheHkgZ2Vz
ZW5kZXQ=

----_com.samsung.android.email_11924222509547450
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

PGh0bWw+PGhlYWQ+PG1ldGEgaHR0cC1lcXVpdj0iQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIiBjb250ZW50PSJ0ZXh0
L2h0bWw7IGNoYXJzZXQ9VVRGLTgiPjwvaGVhZD48Ym9keSBkaXI9ImF1dG8iPkxlb24gV2FyZSB2
b24gTWlyOjxicj4tIExvZ2l0ZWNoIExlbmtyYWQgdCBIYW5kZWw8YnI+LSBQUyA0IGlua2wuIDIg
Y29udHJvbGxlcjxicj4tIExlbm92byBNb25pdG9yPGRpdj48YnI+PC9kaXY+PGRpdj48YnI+PC9k
aXY+PGRpdj48YnI+PC9kaXY+PGRpdj48YnI+PC9kaXY+PGRpdiBpZD0iY29tcG9zZXJfc2lnbmF0
dXJlIj48ZGl2IHN0eWxlPSJmb250LXNpemU6MTJweDtjb2xvcjojNTc1NzU3IiBkaXI9ImF1dG8i
PlZvbiBtZWluZW0vbWVpbmVyIEdhbGF4eSBnZXNlbmRldDwvZGl2PjwvZGl2PjxkaXY+PGJyPjwv
ZGl2PjwvYm9keT48L2h0bWw+

----_com.samsung.android.email_11924222509547450--
```

Excerpt e-mail from Remarkable:

```
X-CMAE-Envelope: 
 MS4xfNVk55TRNs2B6C8cpuJmkKcvMSRZwxUbpMZhZ7Y8lvumn8xQKEhAdfqgdtv2wCFb2LC7Gxv92llU3SvG1Ut5ElO+JO/4AQwXBNUmDk+lrwcnKvN807J8
 w8yA8FUIN2wC5BtLNwazEb5tb12PQREN8jqRc1N3eIA4NpZPPcAx+ZwOpRY03yJn87lAAnzF7l75ZFwTxxLYKu8pZz/ATyZxQ1aFWX5Q7S9WNncfx6GPzK67
 yFOrkkPC9honahTHu2RGig==
X-getmail-retrieved-from-mailbox: INBOX

DOCTYPE html>
html>
body>p>**This is the Note**/p>p>br/><p>/body>
/html>br>br>--br>Sent from my reMarkable paper tabletbr>Get yours at www.remarkable.combr>br>PS: You cannot reply to this emailbr>
```

The message from Remarkable has the block !DOCTYPE html.

I had to edit the HTML part a bit, because otherwise you would not see it as the page interprets it correctly.
This is the Note would be the message in the HTML block that the command cannot convert.

Is it possible that the above command can convert both types?

Thank you very much
Greetings Bruno

Comment: If you mark the HTML as code with the `{}` button you don't need to break it

Comment: What is "remarkable"? Presumably some software, but can you link us to it so we can see what it is?

Comment: Is a pen tablet that can send e-mails.
https://remarkable.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Usage**: executable: `myscript [mail path STR] [output path STR]`
non executable: `bash myscript [mail path STR] [output path STR]`
**Depends On:** commands - html2text, reformime

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
declare section sections=$(reformime -i <"$1")

section=$(grep -zoP " [^\n]*\n[^\n]*text/plain" <<< $sections | head -n 1)
if ((${#section})); then
   section=${section# }; reformime -e -s "$section" < "$1" > "$2"
else
   section=$(grep -zoP " [^\n]*\n[^\n]*text/html" <<< $sections | head -n 1)
   ((${#section})) || { echo "No mimeTypes text/plain or text/html sections found!"; exit; }
   section=${section# }; reformime -e -s "$section" < "$1" | html2text -o "$2"
fi
```

if you dont want a script, define a function in your interactive shell

```
mail2text ()
  {
  local section sections=$(reformime -i <"$1")

  section=$(grep -zoP " [^\n]*\n[^\n]*text/plain" <<< $sections | head -n 1)
  if ((${#section})); then
     section=${section# }; reformime -e -s "$section" < "$1" > "$2"
  else
     section=$(grep -zoP " [^\n]*\n[^\n]*text/html" <<< $sections | head -n 1)
     ((${#section})) || { echo "No mimeTypes text/plain or text/html sections found!"; return; }
     section=${section# }; reformime -e -s "$section" < "$1" | html2text -o "$2"
  fi
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  
Dependencies are installed.

**Executed:** 
`sh reformime.sh /home/bruno/getmail/new/ /home/bruno/`

**Error Message:**

`reformime.sh: 2: declare: not found`  
`reformime.sh: 4: Syntax error: redirection unexpected`

What else is wrong?

Comment: @bruno hello, the script above is a bash shell script, i think your sh is linked to dash shell ```echo $(readlink /bin/sh)``` - Do you have bash installed?, if not, i can rewrite this. But i thought normally bash is an essential package on linux distros?  I definitley want to rewrite this, because  some emails have a text/plain header and content section and a text/html header and content section. But text/plain content could be different content text.

Comment: @bruno For example, i have an email with text/plain section of "Please open with a HTML capable email reader", and the text/html section contains the real message. this script is first searching for text/plain section, if one is found it produces the output with it. The script is only searching for text/html, if no text/plain is found. So that script would produce a text with "Please open with a HTML capable email reader". In your cases the script would work, but in that described case the script would fail.

Comment: hello, Yes I have a bash, sorry my mistake. I just want to run the script with a cronjob scheduled.
The way the script is currently written, it can process a normal e-mail and the e-mail from Remarkable. If you can also implement all other variants (text/html, text/plain header, text/plain) in the script, that would of course be even better.

Comment: hello, Can a new file always be created for the output? If none exists, create a new one and if one exists, count up the values?

It would be ideal if the lines after a certain character were ignored. 
Example:
`this is the note!`
```--
Sent from my reMarkable paper tablet
Get yours at www.remarkable.com

PS: You cannot reply to this email
```

Characters /lines from -- ignore.
Like a variable you can set in the script? Not absolutely necessary, but would be cool.
Thank you very much

Comment: P.s. What else I have noticed. The script cannot handle umlauts.

Comment: Hello,
You can ignore the file name if exists name file it +1.
Regarding text content: It would be ideal if the lines in the text file were ignored after a certain character.

Example: this is the note! -- Sent from my reMarkable paper tablet Get yours at www.remarkable.com PS: You cannot reply to this email

Ignore characters/lines from -- . Like a variable you can set in the script? Not absolutely necessary, but it would be cool.